# How can I connect a specific keyboard key to a DIV element?

Tags: javascript

I have looked online for answers on how to connect a specific keyboard key to a div element and so far what I have been able to only see was how to do a general key(onkeydown) What I am looking for is being a able to press a specific key by using keyCodes to detect that key so that it can call up a DIV element by id and make it active

```
var inpt = document.getElementById("11w");
inpt.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){

e.preventDefault();
if (e.keyCode==49)
document.getELementById("11w").click();
}
});
```

Comment: what you want to do? for example closing a modal by pressing `ESC` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, there is a syntax error in your code.

```
var inpt = document.getElementById("11w");
inpt.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){

e.preventDefault();
if (e.keyCode==49)
document.getELementById("11w").click();
}//<--------- syntax error
});
```

As I understand your question, this may be one of the solutions:

```html
 <textarea id="11w" placeholder="Press 1 or write 1"></textarea>
  <br/>
  <button id="btn">My value will change</button>
  
  <script>
    var inpt = document.getElementById("11w");
    inpt.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e.keyCode);
      if (e.keyCode==49){
        document.getElementById("btn").click();
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e){
      document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "I am clicked";
      console.log("btn clicked");
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I am not looking for an actual button. I am making a virtual piano with keys that are div tags when a key is pressed that div is active for  short  moment

Comment: the button is just an example.

Comment: I understand the button is an example but nothing happens when you press '1' in the code you gave

Comment: what? It does.. if you press 1 in textarea then button text will change.

Comment: I figured it out. I was trying to do it in one event listener i didn't think to use another. Your code helped me thanks!

Comment: I am glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on keyup events of the document then do what you please with each key.

## DEMO

```js
// Assingin to the keyup event of the document
document.onkeyup = (e) => {
  // Getting the div element by it's id #test
  const div = document.querySelector('#test');
  // e.which returns the ascii code of the key that has been pressed
  switch (e.which) {
    case 83:
      // 83 is lower case 's' (show) so we set the div to be block
      div.style.display = 'block';
      break;
    case 72:
      // 72 is lower case h (hide) so we set the div to be none
      div.style.display = 'none';
      break;
  }

};
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

This is just an example showing you how to bind a key to a certain element, it is not by any means bind to it, it just depends on the logic, we can add more logic to control two or more element with press of one key.
the point is that the code you write for each key will fire where you're even when you're typing in an input, that can be avoided, however i'll leave it to you :)

Comment: I just checked out your code. Yes the idea is definitely there I just have to figure out how to do it so it remains active as long as the key is still being pressed. since what I am trying to do is make a virtual piano as in a button is pressed then that key becomes active for a short time and becomes like an actual piano ps I am using div tags for the keys

Comment: listen on the `keypressed` event, in your case you'll probably have to use both . Check these links [DOM EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp),
[DOM Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp)

Comment: I have  tried to use event listener and still no available. What I am looking for is to make that div id active (if (e.keyCode==81){
        but.getElementByClassName("whiteKey:active");
      }) when I press 'q' nothing happens

Comment: That's not how you add a class to an element. try this `but.getElementByClassName("the currrent element class").classList.add('class name you want to add');`